# Error cross-compiling qt5 project with mxe using function introduce in Qt5

Tags: c++, windows, qt, cross-platform, ubuntu-12.04

I've tried to cross-compile a Qt5 project using mxe, which seems to work as long as I'm not using any functions introduced with the Qt5.
I'm using Ubuntu, the following steps lead to my problem:
1.
I followed the mxe-tutorial found here: http://mxe.cc/#tutorial to build qt5.
2.
I cross-compiled a small test project, which worked excellent up to the point where I used the function `QTime:: int msecsSinceStartOfDay() const`
I get the following error when running the make command:

> main.cpp:10:57: error: 'class QTime' has no member named 'msecsSinceStartOfDay' QString msSinceStartOfDay = QString ("%1").arg(time.msecsSinceStartOfDay())

I can't figure out the problem, I think using a function introduced in Qt5 should work, because I'm using the qmake of Qt5.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you for your time David